# \tabto to tab again in new line

Tags: tabto

I'm looking for a method to modify my tabto-command so if the text is to long to fit in one line, the text will be tabbed again in the new line.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, twosides, openany, liststotoc]{scrbook}

\usepackage{tabto}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand*{\mytab}{\tabto{4.5cm}}

\begin{document}

    \begin{itemize}
        \item One \mytab{\lipsum[4]}
        \item Two \mytab{\lipsum[4]}
    \end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Thankful greetings
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than try to do this exclusively with `tabto`, one could bring in a `\parbox`.  Then you just need to know the widths involved to define the width of the `\parbox`.

However, this `tabto` method will not break items across page boundaries.

It would be preferable to dispense with the `tabto` and use `enumitem`  to achieve the same thing, because it will break across page boundaries.

In the MWE below, I use the `tabto` method on item "One" and the `enumitem` method on item "Two".

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, twosides, openany, liststotoc]{scrbook}

\usepackage{tabto,enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand*{\mytab}[1]{\tabto{4.5cm}\parbox[t]{%
  \dimexpr\textwidth-4.5cm-\labelwidth-\labelsep}{#1}}
\begin{document}

    \begin{itemize}
        \item One \mytab{The \texttt{tabto} way  that will not
              break across page boundaries. \lipsum[4]}
        \item Two 
          \vspace{\dimexpr-\baselineskip-\parskip}
          \begin{itemize}[label=,leftmargin=4.5cm,topsep=0pt]
          \item The \texttt{enumitem} way that will break across
                page boundaries. \lipsum[4-7]
          \end{itemize}
    \end{itemize}

\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response. Works absolutely fine.
The prevention to break across pages is even quite good for my purpose.
Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @Psykes For completeness, I added a 2nd method to allow breaks across page boundaries.  By the way, if my answer is wholly suitable to your needs, you could indicate so to the community (and me) by clicking the check mark to the left of my answer.  This is called "accepting" the answer, and tells others that this approach solved your problem best (if multiple answers were provided).